# Camel Rabbit doesn't allow to set empty routing key when declaring DLX

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Camel Rabbit to consume messages from a queue. I use an URI to declare the queue with a dead letter exchange, but I'm not supplying the option `deadLetterRoutingKey` as I want the messages going to DLX to keep the original routing key. When the application starts it throws the following error:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error;
    protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid arg 'x-dead-letter-routing-key' for queue 'entry.paid.erp' in vhost '/': {unacceptable_type,void}, class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

Is it possible to configure Camel to have this behavior?

Some additional information:

- Camel version: 2.19.1
- Spring Boot version: 1.5.4.RELEASE
- Example of URI I'm using:

  ```
  rabbitmq://server:port/my-exchange
      ?connectionFactory=#connectionFactory
      &exchangeType=topic
      &queue=my-queue
      &autoAck=true
      &durable=true
      &autoDelete=false
      &exclusive=false
      &automaticRecoveryEnabled=true
      &concurrentConsumers=15
      &deadLetterExchange=dlx-exchange
      &deadLetterExchangeType=fanout
      &deadLetterQueue=dlx-queue
  ```
- When I set a value for `deadLetterRoutingKey` the application starts with no errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the original routingKey get replaced by the deadLetterRoutingKey if you set it?

Comment: Yes, the message in the queue routed by the dead letter exchange will have   its routing key equals to the `deadLetterRoutingKey`. I can extract the original routing key using the `x-death` attributes but I can't use these attributes to perform any routing logic between the DLX and its bound queues.

Comment: It could be that this is a feature that needs to be added to the camel-component.  Maybe create a jira issue on the Camel jira site and let the developers know. They are usually quick to respond.